# Javascript / Jquery reading text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is a lot of information about reading data from local file in javascript but I'd like to ensure myself that there is no possibility to just display window to pick file path and read it, everything on the client side. Just YES/NO

I need to write a script which generates schedule completely on the client side. Is there any way to do this except copy-paste data into some text area?

P.S
I clarified my first question

Answer (score 4):

Javascript cannot create files on the client-side. It would be a massive security risk if it were allowed to do so.

The general pattern is to create the file on the server (either physically or in memory) and serve it to the user for download.